# Skip particular repetition in nested foor loop - Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
for k in range(8):
    for i in range(2): #number of columns
        for j in range(4): #number of row
            print(k,j,i)
```

I want an output like this. no repetition of first for loop

```
k,j,i
-----
0 0 0
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 3 0
4 0 1
5 1 1 
6 2 1
7 3 1
```

How I will achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Normally i would do

```py
for i in range(8):
    print(i, i%4, i%2)
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 0
3 3 1
4 0 0
5 1 1
6 2 0
7 3 1
```

---

But to reproduce your exact output:

```py
for i in range(8):
    print(i, i%4, int(i>3))
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 3 0
4 0 0
5 1 1
6 2 1
7 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements to say things like `if k == 7` or something along those lines. This will only allow it to loop the first loop before moving on to the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have shown similar ways to produce your exact output, but this is another way to do it, and this would still work if you wanted the number of rows to be more than 8 and you wanted i to keep increasing

```
for i in range(8):
    print(i, i%4, i//4)
```

I hope this is useful, sorry if it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `i` and `j`, you have the cartesian product of `{0,1}` and `{0,1,2,3}`. You can compute that with `itertools.product(range(2), range(4))`, then use `enumerate` to number them for your `k` value.

```
from itertools import product


for k, (i, j) in enumerate(product(range(2), range(4))):
    print(k, j, i)
```

Earlier arguments to `product` vary more slowly than later arguments.